# 3 column content in homepage with 1 column layout in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout

I want to create a 3 column content on homepage which is having layout property as 1 column . How can i do this without changing the default layout of homepage?

Can i create a block with 3 columns and add it to the homepage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller execute method place the following piece of code which should set your desired layout.

```
  public function execute()
{

     $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create(false, ['isIsolated' => true]);           

     $customLayout = '3columns';

     $page->getConfig()->setPageLayout($customLayout);
     return $page;
}
```